# dbm-update not working after upgrading to 2.1.2

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

grails dbm-update suppose to execute all the db changes provided in changelog.goovy. It used to work very well in 2.1.1 but after upgrading the app to 2.1.2 it stopped working. It doesn't give any error but it simply doesn't execute the changelog. Any comments.

Comment: Run it with --stacktrace --verbose